# GLM Poisson Regression Understanding R Output for tests

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression

```
> pasSmoking.dat=data.frame(freq=c(21,73,5,19,71,137,82,188,16,38,249,363))
> pasSmoking.dat$Cnt=factor(rep(c("Japan","UK", "USA"), times=2, each=2))
> pasSmoking.dat$Smo=factor(rep(c("No","Yes"), times=6))
> pasSmoking.dat$Can=factor(rep(c("Case","Control"), each=6))
> pasSmoking.dat

   freq   Cnt Smo     Can
1    21 Japan  No    Case
2    73 Japan Yes    Case
3     5    UK  No    Case
4    19    UK Yes    Case
5    71   USA  No    Case
6   137   USA Yes    Case
7    82 Japan  No Control
8   188 Japan Yes Control
9    16    UK  No Control
10   38    UK Yes Control
11  249   USA  No Control
12  363   USA Yes Control
> mod1=glm(freq~Cnt+Smo+Can+Cnt:Smo+Cnt:Can+Smo:Can, family=poisson, data=pasSmoking.dat)
> anova(mod1, test="Chisq")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: poisson, link: log

Response: freq

Terms added sequentially (first to last)


        Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev  Pr(>Chi)    
NULL                       11    1168.85              
Cnt      2   726.43         9     442.42 < 2.2e-16 ***
Smo      1   112.52         8     329.90 < 2.2e-16 ***
Can      1   307.56         7      22.34 < 2.2e-16 ***
Cnt:Smo  2    15.50         5       6.84 0.0004316 ***
Cnt:Can  2     1.05         3       5.80 0.5919109    
Smo:Can  1     5.56         2       0.24 0.0184215 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> 1-pchisq(0.24,2)
[1] 0.8869204
> 1-pchisq(5.80,3)
[1] 0.1217566
```

I'm trying to test, based on the model, (1) the significance of the interaction effect **Smo:Can**, eliminating the effects of all other terms on the model
and (2) the adequacy of the model **Cnt+Smo+Can+Cnt:Smo+Cnt:Can** (note that Smo:Can is excluded here) at a significance level of 0.05.

```
        Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev  Pr(>Chi)    
Smo:Can  1     5.56         2       0.24 0.0184215 *
```

I believe the P-value above is the test of (1) but I'm not completely sure that other effects are eliminated here since the residual df and deviance seem to be following from other effects. I guess what I'm unsure about most is whether that p value tests the significance of Smo:Can to the model or a significant interaction effect between Smo and Can.

```
> 1-pchisq(5.80,3)
[1] 0.1217566
```

Above is what seems to be the test for model adequacy of (2) which seems to be insignificant but with a much lower p value than the model with **Smo:Can** and seems to be more adequate. I was wondering why this is the case if **Smo:Can** is significant as we saw above.

Comment: What do you mean *eliminating the effects of all other terms on the model*? It sounds as if you want to compare the model "freq~Smo:Can" to "freq~1" which would be strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe the P-value above is the test of (1) but I'm not completely sure that other effects are eliminated here since the residual df and deviance seem to be following from other effects.

The ANOVA test and its output adds model terms sequentially, in the order listed.  So in this case, the listed p-value of `0.0184215` for the `Smo:Can` term is for a model that already has all the previous terms (listed above this) in the model.  I presume this is what you mean when you refer to the other terms being "eliminated".

Comment: Does this mean that this will give the p-value for the test "the significance of the interaction effect Smo:Can, eliminating the effects of all
other terms in the model"?

Edit: I've posted the R code I'm referring to above as I'm unsure how to write code in comments

Comment: It depends what you mean by "eliminating".  It tests whether that term is present in a model that has already included all those other terms.

Comment: I agree the wording is confusing. It seems to me that "eliminating all other effects in the model" means having only that term in the model Thanks for your help