# How to assess differences in sets of data with yearly rates

Tags: r, time-series, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test

I have a dataset that is composed of homicide rates (per 100,000 or per 10,000) from 1980-2014 for 11 geographical areas. I need to assess whether there are statistically differing rates between the geographical areas over those 24 years. I am not certain how to approach this analysis or what would be the best way to go about testing for difference. Chi-squared testing has been suggested to me but I'm still unsure how to apply it to this dataset. Would you be able to suggest a way to assess for statistically significant differences between these geographical areas over the time specified? If possible, could you suggest ways to approach this using R software?

Comment: What is the specific hypothesis you want to test? A trend of change over the 24 year period, or a difference between the average rate over all 24 years, or something else?

Comment: I'm looking to establish whether a difference exists in any pairwise comparison of the areas over the 24 year span

Comment: Then you would need a full multivariate model.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a time series (or multiple time series, one for each area) of yearly counts. I would start out with Poisson regression, with $\log(10 000)$ or $\log(100 000)$ as an offset, so as to modeling *rates*. This is called Poisson rate regression, search this site. You must have an eye out for possible *overdispersion*.

As for the time series aspect, [look through this earlier Qs with answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=poisson+time+series+regression+answers%3A1).  As for using R, this post [Modeling multivariate Time Series Count Data in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244660/modeling-multivariate-time-series-count-data-in-r)  have jags code run from R, [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/405369/glm-poisson-regression-understanding-r-output-for-tests) have some pure R code.